# Finding indices of the lowest 5 numbers of an array in Python

Tags: python

How to find out which indices belong to the lowest `x` (say, 5) numbers of an array?

`[10.18398473,   9.95722384,   9.41220631, 9.42846614,   9.7300549 ,   9.69949144,   9.86997862, 10.28299122,   9.97274071,  10.08966867,   9.7]`

Also, how to directly find the sorted (from low to high) lowest `x` numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existing answers are nice, but here's the solution if you're using `numpy`:

```
mylist = np.array([10.18398473, 9.95722384, 9.41220631, 9.42846614, 9.7300549 , 9.69949144, 9.86997862, 10.28299122, 9.97274071, 10.08966867, 9.7])
x = 5
lowestx = np.argsort(mylist)[:x]
#array([ 2,  3,  5, 10,  4])
```

Comment: I was just about to post this solution (+1)

Comment: I am using numpy, and this is really the easiest to read solution.

Comment: Btw, you probably want to replace that `:5` with `:x`

Comment: In that case, there are several nice `np.arg...` functions like this that you should learn.

Comment: @askewchan Can you recommend a source?

Comment: @Dualinity, Personally I use: `ipython`; `np.arg<tab>` to get a list, then `np.argmin?`.  But there's also a nice [numpy tutorial](http://scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial) and great [example list](http://scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List) which doubles as readable documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> l = [5, 1, 2, 4, 6]
>>> sorted(range(len(l)), key=lambda i: l[i])
[1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = [10.18398473, 9.95722384, 9.41220631, 9.42846614, 9.7300549 , 9.69949144, 9.86997862, 10.28299122, 9.97274071, 10.08966867, 9.7]

# lowest 5
lowest = sorted(mylist)[:5]

# indices of lowest 5
lowest_ind = [i for i, v in enumerate(mylist) if v in lowest]

# 5 indices of lowest 5
import operator
lowest_5ind = [i for i, v in sorted(enumerate(mylist), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[:5]]
```

Comment: Try getting the indexes of the lowest five members of `[0, 1, 2, 4] + [5] * 10` and you'll see why this algorithm doesn't always work.

Comment: @Dietrich it still gives the index of the lowest 5 members, just the last of the lowest five occurs many places.  Not sure how he would want this case handled.

Comment: Your code doesn't solve that problem either (try `[0] * 5 + [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`).  Either you should select the least five different values and return all indexes, or you should select five indexes giving the least five values.  The code presented chooses neither of the sensible alternatives.

Comment: @DietrichEpp in that case the lowest 5 are all zeros.  I solved the problem as stated.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a.index(b) for b in sorted(a)[:5]]
sorted(a)[.x]
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO], thanks for your answer!  If you indent lines with code by four spaces, they'll be formatted nicely.